# Position elements relative to parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slideshow that looks like this:

```
<div class="slideshow_cont">
    <div class="slideshow_btn_cont">
    </div>
    <ul class="slideshow">  
    {% for obj in project_list %}
    <li class="slide"> 
    <img class="slideshow_thumb"/>
    <span class="slideshow_thumb_label">
    {{ obj.project_title }}
    </span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
.slideshow_cont{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow{
    height:150px;
    width:2000px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position:absolute;
    list-style:none;
}
.slide{
    width: 140px;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 40;
}
```

How can I add margin

between the first slide and the left border of the `slideshow_cont`and

between the last slide and the right border of the `slideshow_cont`,

so that the slides don't overlap with the buttons?

[image]

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I added this function to set the slideshow width equal to slides width x slides n + margin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slide_ = $('.slide');
    var slide_w =  slide_.width();
    var slide_n = slide_.length;
    var slide_m = slide_n * 80; // margin
    slideshow_width = slide_n * slide_w + slide_m;
    $('.slideshow').css({'width':slideshow_width});
});
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo classes to add the margins

Or use padding on the container

Comment: Thank you, but in this case the slideshow has a width of 2000px and the slides are centered. Adding margin or padding to the first or last slide won't have any effect, unless there are enough slides to fill up the slideshow. Same for padding